# Magento 2.1 Cannot Update Multi-select Attributes for Multiple Products

Tags: attributes, custom-attributes, multiselect-attribute, massaction

Anyone else having this issue? I have created a couple of new attributes (with multi-select) and when I try to mass update this attribute across 9 products simultaneously it doesn't update (although it says it's successful.)

I can update the attribute if I click into each product individually.

Comment: I also had this Problem with product visibility. Seems to be a Bug Not Limited to custom attributes

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar issue - if add to custom attribute set custom multi select attribute (and it's not in default) they don't save. But after first try i run `cache:clean` and from this moment everything goes fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered that this is a bug in Magento 2.1 and here is the patch to fix this.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5459

I used different file paths for 2.1:                                          vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute/Tab/Attributes.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Action/Attribute/Save.php

Also, in the attributes.php I removed the old line and in the save.php I added the new one underneath the old one